# Can a query be used in place of a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

This should really be allowed - I do not understand why it is not.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM MyTable
)
```

Comment: If you post code or XML - **please** always highlight the lines in question and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar! That makes it just soooo much easier and nicer to read!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In SQL Server it is allowed, but the inner select has to be given a name, such as:

```
SELECT *  
FROM ( 
    SELECT *  
    FROM MyTable
) m
```

When a name is not supplied it will throw an incorrect syntax error near ')' message.

Answer (score 6):

If you add a table alias it should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM MyTable
) as A
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing an 'alias' on the sub-query
(I added an alias 'X' )

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM MyTable
) X
```

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways to accomplish this, but what you might be looking for is a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx), introduced in SQL Server 2005.

From the above link:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, NumberOfOrders, MaxDate)
AS
(
    SELECT SalesPersonID, COUNT(*), MAX(OrderDate)
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    GROUP BY SalesPersonID
)
SELECT E.EmployeeID, OS.NumberOfOrders, OS.MaxDate,
    E.ManagerID, OM.NumberOfOrders, OM.MaxDate
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS E
    JOIN Sales_CTE AS OS
    ON E.EmployeeID = OS.SalesPersonID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales_CTE AS OM
    ON E.ManagerID = OM.SalesPersonID
ORDER BY E.EmployeeID;
GO
```

Alternately, you can create a [View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx), which is a permanent table-shaped representation of a query that you can access by name:

```
USE AdventureWorks ;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID ('hiredate_view', 'V') IS NOT NULL
DROP VIEW hiredate_view ;
GO
CREATE VIEW hiredate_view
AS 
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, e.EmployeeID, e.HireDate
FROM HumanResources.Employee e JOIN Person.Contact c on e.ContactID = c.ContactID ;
GO
SELECT * FROM hiredate_view
```

Comment: -1: You don't need a view or CTE to do this, it's a standard subquery.

Comment: @OrbMan, the OP's code does not use a subquery.  a subquery is `a SELECT query that returns a single value and is nested inside a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement, or inside another subquery. A subquery can be used anywhere an expression is allowed.` the OP uses a derived table, which is sometimes called an inline view.

Comment: @KM - you are correct. I have lazily fallen into the habit of using the name *subquery* for any query in brackets, but derived table is the proper term, and what I really meant.